# Homography computation of a deformed square planar object

Tags: computer-vision, homography

suppose you have a square planar object (a piece of paper). You take a photo of it. Generally speaking, it will appear deformed. Suppose you process the image and compute the four corners of the planar object. Given the four points, you can compute an homography.

But now suppose that the object undergoes some type of deformation. All we can say about the nature of the deformation is:

1. it is "smooth" ( the surface of the object will not form sharp angles)
2. the surface of the object will be always totally visible even after the deformation.

For example: you stick the square paper on the surface of a cylindrical object.

The question is: given *only* the four coordinates (in pixel) of the corners of the planar (deformed) object, can i compute the correct homography? That is, can i "remove" the effect of the deformation before computing the homograhy?

Even an "approximated" (read working ;) method would be really useful. 
Thanks.

Ps.
I wish to add that i don't know, a priori, the content of the planar object. Infact, the algorithm i am writing computes the homography, unwarp the object and check its content. It is a 2D barcode, so i have a pair id/crc of numbers. If the crc extracted from the object is equal to the crc computed on the id then it is a valid barcode.

Comment: Do you know anything else besides the 4 corner points? Dimensions of the square plane? Distance between camera and plane? Is the plane guaranteed to be square or is it rectangular?

Comment: The distance is not knonw. The object printed on the paper is square. We can also compute its countour. I said that the content of the image is not known a priori, but suppose that once the square object is detected, we can associate it with N possible images (with N small, say below 10). I was thinking of using some sort of deformable template matching between the deformed object and the N images, but that would be probably slow. And consider that the square object is a 2D barcode. So the RGB used for its design are (0,0,0) and (255,255,255)...

Answer (score 1):

A homography is by definition a plane-plane transform. If the barcode is small enough you could probably assume that the object it is attached to is piecewise planar. After rectifying the image of the barcode you could estimate a barrel distortion model.

If you want to remove the deformation first then you would have to estimate the surface first and then flatten it. That would be a lot more difficult.

Comment: There are pixel-based image registration methods that are able to match two images even in presence of deformations. Given the fact that i know the ROI (that is, i know the contour of the object in the photo), i could use some of those methods. Otherwise, another way is to first compute the homography and then unwarp the object. After that, suppose you have one possible target image (the reference, undeformed template). Use that image and a pixel-based image registration robust to deformations and compute the registration error. If this is too high, the objects doens't match very well...

Comment: What transformation model are you using for the pixel registration methods ? They have to use some kind of projective model, a homography is a planar projective model. I don't see how what you are saying here is any different to what I am proposing in my answer. When I said "rectify the image" I mean warp it into the plane of the camera = unwarp. You wouldn't need to do registration after that.

Comment: Why are you talking about using registration error to "match objects" ? I thought you were going to unwarp the barcode + undistort it and then read it ? Or are you going to do a visual comparison against an image of a candidate bar code ?

Comment: You are right. I need to compute the homography even in presence of deformations because i need to compute the identification code of the object. If there are no deformations, this computation will give a reliable answer (yes, it is a valid object and its code is XYZ, or not, it is not a valid object). Otherwise, one obtain a list of possible matches (which are images afterall). After obtaining the list, i could run the registration method robust to deformations (one registration per hypothesis) and see if the best candidate has a small enough error.

Comment: My original question was more on the geometric side: since straight lines are straight lines even after perspective projection, if i found that some of the four straight lines of the contour of the object are not straight anymore, maybe i could use this fact to "remove" the deformation...

Comment: You're confusing me a little when you say you would estimate a homography and then a registration because a homography is a registration; I don't see why you would need to estimate another registration. Exactly, after rectifying the image, lines in the barcode that are not straight are due to distortion.

Comment: Ok, don't think about the homography for now. The problem is: you have two WxH images. I just want to compute the minimum SSD using some sort of deformable lucas-kanade registration method. If this score is too high, the two images are probably depicting different objects.